# Javascript target ahref and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a snipit of JS target this HMTL. I've tried to enter the class in the javascript but think it maybe the wrong way of doing it.

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#contentm" class="tablet">Projects.t</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
$("a[href='#contentm .tablet']").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 500 : 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you have a dedicated click handler for this one element, you might as well give it an ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a.tablet[href='#contentm']").click(function () {
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 500 : 0
}, "slow");
return false;
});
```

Your order was a bit messed up

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a[href='#contentm'].tablet").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 500 : 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Is what you want I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
try $("a.tablet[href='#contentm']")
```